# Get binary representation of integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I just had an interview question, where I need to get the binary representation of an integer, this is something I should know how to do.. for example, 5 is represented in binary as 101, and the steps look something like:

```
// 5 % 2 = 1
// 5 / 2 = 2
// result = 1;

// 2 % 2 = 0
// 2 / 2 = 1
// result = 10

// 1 % 2 = 1
// 1 / 2 = 0
// result = 101
```

the stopping condition is when `~~(1/2) === 0`

so I have this:

```
const getBinary = (v) => {

  let remainder, binary = 1;

  while (true) {

    remainder = v % 2;
    v = ~~(v / 2);

    if (v === 0) {
      return binary;
    }

    if (remainder === 0) {
      binary = binary * 10 + 1;
    }
    else {
      binary = binary * 10;
    }
  }

};

console.log(getBinary(5));
```

so that works, but the `binary` variable is initialized to 1. Is there a way to improve this so it works with negative numbers, or if 0 is passed as the argument to the function?

Comment: this is not quite right. For 10 it returns 1101

Comment: yep maybe so, looking for something that is correct

Comment: Should the negatives be using [two's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_compliment), [one's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) or just a `-` sign in front of the binary representation?

Answer (score 7):

```
var integer = 52;
console.log(integer.toString(2));
```

Simple function native to javascript, no lengthy code required.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write it from scratch you can use something like this:

```js
function toBinary(n) {
    n = Number(n);
    if (n == 0) return '0';
    var r = '';
    while (n != 0) {
        r = ((n&1)?'1':'0') + r;
        n = n >>> 1;
    }
    return r;
}
console.log(toBinary(5));
console.log(toBinary(10));
console.log(toBinary(-5));
console.log(toBinary(0));
```

Comment: Using the shift operator `>>>` is kind of cheating but good answer nevertheless! +1.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out if you want to reverse this, you will need to cast to an Int32, as bitwise OP's in JS are limited to 32bits.

Answer (score 2):

So here is one way. It has an inner function that handles the basics and an outer one that extends to your special cases. I preferred to do string representations.

```js
const getBinary = v => {
   if (v === 0) return '';
   let remainder = v % 2;
   let quotient = (v - remainder) / 2;
   if (remainder === 0) {
      return getBinary(quotient) + '0';
   }
   else {
      return getBinary(quotient) + '1';
   }
}

const betterGetBinary = v => {
   if (v === 0) return '0';
   if (v < 0) return '-' + getBinary(-v);
   return getBinary(v);
}

console.log(betterGetBinary(-10));
```

Comment: thanks for the edits @ibrahim mahrir . That is better formatted and more direct in its logic. And to your comment above, I was assuming just - sign in front of the normal, but the question may have wanted otherwise.

Comment: This version has the added bonus of been able to handle numbers greater than 32bits..  And is more compatible to how `toString(2)` works.

Comment: You're welcome! You should really consider reading the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), a lot of great stuff in there. Great answer by the way, I'm still waiting for OP to respond to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087074/get-binary-representation-of-integer#comment91125023_52087074) to see if it's really what he is looking for. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution, although it 'might' have two flaws:
- `Math.floor()`
- no bitwise operator

```js
let getBinary = number => {
  let done = false;
  let resultInverted = [];
  let acc = number;
  while (!done) {
    let reminder = acc % 2;
    if (acc === 1) {
      done = true;
    }
    acc = Math.floor(acc / 2);
    resultInverted.push(reminder);
  }
  return Number(resultInverted.reverse().join(''));
};

console.log(typeof getBinary(2));
console.log(getBinary(5));
console.log(getBinary(127));
```

Comment: you can use `while(true)` and then in the `if(acc === 1)` just put the return statement there